# Search for values in arrays

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've a spreadsheet with two sheets (Foglio1, Foglio2)
Foglio1 has five rows of numeric values in two columns, Foglio2 2 has five rows of numeric values in the first column.
I'd like to search for the Foglio2 values in Foglio1 and if it finds something copy the respective value of Foglio1, column2 into Foglio2, column2.

This is what I've got so far but it doesn't seems to work, basically it doesn't find anything so the result array remains empty

```js
function cercaCopia() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('myfileIDhere');
  var data1 = ss.getSheetByName('Foglio2').getRange(1, 1, 5).getValues();
  var data2 = ss.getSheetByName('Foglio1').getRange(1, 1, 5, 2).getValues();
  var result = new Array(4);

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      if (data1[i] == data2[j, 0]) {
        result[i] = data2[j, 1]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First all results from Range#getValues() are 2 dimensional arrays.

second 2 dimensional arrays in JS are actually just arrays of arrays and need to be referenced data2[j][0]

third your results array should also be 2 dimensional if you intend to pass it to Range#setValues();

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetid');
 var data1 = ss.getSheetByName('Foglio2').getRange(1, 1, 5).getValues();
 var data2 = ss.getSheetByName('Foglio1').getRange(1, 1, 5, 2).getValues();

 for (var j=0; j<5;j++){
   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     if (data1[j][0]==data2[i][0]){
        var range= ss.getSheetByName('Foglio2').getRange(1,1,5,5);
        range.getCell(j+1,2).setValue(data2[i][1]);
     }
   }
 } 
}
```

I get this as a result:

[image]

In Foglio1 I had this:

[image]